# CSS: Dynamic adjust of width depending on content

Tags: css, width

This is a problem I at first didn't thought was so problematic, and perhaps it aint, but I haven't found a solution yet. I've tried a few different approaches but didn't really get the correct solution.

I've tried to show in this picture.

[image]

1. When the topic is short, the comment count should follow after directly.
2. When the topic is longer, it should be cut (hidden) and the comment count should only take up as much width as it has to.
3. The above should work even when the comment count is longer/shorter.

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: It's doable, but it's not trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/xGWsa/

Comment: Great solution, works like a charm, only problem is js. Would be great if someone could work this out with CSS.

Comment: @Martin Note that you can achieve a decent effect by just having the comments on the right: http://jsfiddle.net/xGWsa/2/

Comment: @Šime Yes, I though so too, but the client didn't :) I also tried a max-width approach on the left element, but that locks the comment count to a certain width, which is bad.